# Multiple small questions = 1 post, or multiple?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I am studying for the GRE by using practice books and taking practice exams. The answers are included for all questions, but not an explanation. I was able to deduce or otherwise help myself figure out the answer to most of the questions I missed, minus about 7. Unable to find answers with google or targeted math help sites, and knowing no one who is good at math nearby my place of residence, I thought it only reasonable to come here.

Given that these questions are elementary in nature (high-school, early college level), is it appropriate to ask these 7 or so questions in a single post, or should I create 7 threads, no matter how trivial may seem to be?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ask about a concept you're not familiar with that's preventing you from checking your own answers. If you can't isolate that concept, ask about the questions in separate posts, but space them out - if the questions are related, you might learn enough from the first question that you don't have to ask the others, and in any case it's a little impolite to fill the questions page with only your questions.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks